# Failed to suspend process in c++ program

Tags: c++, winapi, process, resume, suspend

```cpp
private:
DWORD SuspendProcess(HANDLE hProcess) {
    DWORD result = SuspendThread(hProcess);

    if (result == (DWORD)-1) {
        // SuspendThread failed
        return false;
    }

    return true;
    /*HANDLE hThreadSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD,
    0); DWORD suspendCount = 0;

    if (hThreadSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        THREADENTRY32 te32 = {};
        te32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

        if (Thread32First(hThreadSnapshot, &te32)) {
            do {
                if (te32.th32OwnerProcessID == GetProcessId(hProcess)) {
                    DWORD threadId = te32.th32ThreadID;
                    HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME,
    FALSE, threadId); if (hThread != NULL) { suspendCount +=
    SuspendThread(hThread); CloseHandle(hThread);
                    }
                }
            } while (Thread32Next(hThreadSnapshot, &te32));
        }

        CloseHandle(hThreadSnapshot);
    }*/

    // return suspendCount;
}
```

```cpp
private:
VOID ResumeProcess(HANDLE hProcess) {
    HANDLE hThreadSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);

    if (hThreadSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        THREADENTRY32 te32 = {};
        te32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

        if (Thread32First(hThreadSnapshot, &te32)) {
            do {
                if (te32.th32OwnerProcessID == GetProcessId(hProcess)) {
                    DWORD threadId = te32.th32ThreadID;
                    HANDLE hThread =
                        OpenThread(THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME, FALSE, threadId);
                    if (hThread != NULL) {
                        ResumeThread(hThread);
                        CloseHandle(hThread);
                    }
                }
            } while (Thread32Next(hThreadSnapshot, &te32));
        }

        CloseHandle(hThreadSnapshot);
    }
}
```

I've written these functions to suspend and resume process, that i create in my project. But when i try to suspend process, i have an error: Failed to suspend the process. i've tried to run visual studio as an administrator, but it didn't change anything. Hope you will find an error :)

Comment: use `ZwSuspendProcess` - single api call

Comment: and of course `SuspendThread(hProcess);` for process handle is error

Comment: What is the specific problem you need to solve by suspending a process?

Comment: When most Win32 APIs fail, you can usually use `GetLastError()` to find out WHY it failed (check the documentation to make sure). In this case, all of the APIs you are calling report error codes via `GetLastError()`. So, when you get the `Failed to suspend the process` error, what is the OS telling you about WHY it failed?

Comment: We have to know what the process was doing. If a process attempts to allocate memory from the stack, the behavior of `suspendthread` is unsafe. Please  use the `GetLastError` function to get extended error information.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT What's particularly *"unsafe"* about `sub rsp, #imm` that makes the "process" of *"allocating memory from the stack"* more dangerous when suspending a thread than everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your process handle has all access; if it doesn't, just open a separate handle using `OpenProcess` and passing `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`.

For suspending and resuming, I recommend using `NtSuspendProcess` and `NtResumeProcess`.

Here's an example on how you can call these:

```
static auto nt_suspend_process = reinterpret_cast< LONG( __stdcall* )( HANDLE ) >( GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandleA( "ntdll.dll" ), "NtSuspendProcess" ) );

static auto nt_resume_process = reinterpret_cast< void( __stdcall* )( HANDLE ) >( GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandleA( "ntdll.dll" ), "NtResumeProcess" ) );
```

Comment: i made what u said, but also get an error: failed to suspend a process

Comment: hmm, what process? also did you try running your compiled program as admin?